# Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine, jestjs

I'm getting following error when I try to test an angular component:

Error while running jest tests:

```
Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

Here is my html:

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>`
```

I'm using `"@angular/material": "6.1.0",` in my package.json.
I've also imported all the required material dependencies in the `beforeAll` block under `TestBed`
I also tried changing the property of the button from `matMenuTriggerFor` to `mat-menu-trigger-for`. It didn't work.

Please suggest how can I fix this test.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Import **`MatMenuModule`** in your feature Module OR the Module where this component resides in.

```
 import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
```

and

```
imports: [
  MatMenuModule
]
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add the MatMenuModule import to your app.module file.

Answer (score 2):

Random but in case someone was searching like me: I was importing a custom angular material library and building the consuming library before building the material library. when I built the material library first then the consuming library was about to see the MatMenuModule and errors went away.

I changed

```
"library:build": "npm run ng7-common:build" && npm run ng8-material:build
```

to:

```
"library:build": " npm run ng8-material:build && npm run ng7-common:build"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this (and several other errors) because I failed to add the component to the `declarations` array in the `lib.module.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling I had one `g` in word `trigger` that cost me this error

```
[matMenuTrigerData] => [matMenuTriggerData]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while running `jest` test.  I had to add `MatMenuModule` in the import array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

If imports at other module, you need export MatMenuModule.

At your module, place:

...
exports: [MatMenuModule],
...

Answer (score 0):

import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';