# Can't bind to 'MatMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

ERROR : Can't bind to 'MatMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

MY CODE APPCOMPONENT.HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5 justify-content-end">
    <a mat-button>Login</a>
    <a mat-button>Logout</a>
    <a mat-button>Register</a>
    <a mat-button [MatMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Management</a>
    <mat-menu #menu>
        <a mat-button>Dashboard</a>
        <a mat-button>M-Categories</a>
        <a mat-button>M-Useres</a>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: This should answer your quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883873/cant-bind-to-matmenutriggerfor-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883873/cant-bind-to-matmenutriggerfor-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-button)

Comment: Also, it's matMenuTriggerFor, with lowercase 'm' (yours is capital).